systemd to control a daemon written in python
I have acquired a python script that is invoked at the command line and immediately returns having demonised and two processes have spawned. Unsure why two but one is the parent of the other.
I wish to use systemd to (a) ensure it starts on boot, (b) is restarted if it crashes.
I cannot make it work. Neither systemd nor python are my speciality.
The difficulty I think is in the systemd Service definition.  As the script daemonises itself the awareness of its state (running as a daemon process) is not being understood by systemd.
This is the systemd file I place in /etc/systemd/system and use systemctl to enable and start it.
Description=python daemon script

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/script-as-daemon
RestartSec=5s
Restart=always
RuntimeMaxSec=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

If I start it with 'systemctl start script-as-daemon' then it might start briefly (hard to tell), but certainly doesn't behave as it does if I just invoke it manually.
I have tried various other Type= values even though they make little sense given what the script is doing, but can't find any solution.
The python script calls the function:
def createDaemon():

   try:
      pid = os.fork()
   except OSError, e:
      raise Exception, "%s [%d]" % (e.strerror, e.errno)

   if (pid == 0):   # The first child.
      os.setsid()

      try:
         pid = os.fork()    # Fork a second child.
      except OSError, e:
         raise Exception, "%s [%d]" % (e.strerror, e.errno)

      if (pid == 0):    # The second child.
         os.chdir(WORKDIR)
         os.umask(UMASK)
      else:
         os._exit(0)    # Exit parent (the first child) of the second child.
   else:
      os._exit(0)   # Exit parent of the first child.

And after that does
input, output = os.pipe()
    pid           = os.fork()

    if pid:
        os.close(input)
        callPythonScriptA
    else:
        os.close(output)
        callPythonScriptB

In amongst that I hope is a clue to how I need to tune the systemd config to allow the python script to start and daemonise in a way that it continues while satisfying what systemd expects when it is invoked.
Another method I consider is to write a shell script to start the python script and then use system to call the shell script. But they seems messy and duplicating what system is designed to do.
Many thanks.
r.

Type=forking is generally meant for older-style services/daemons where an init script would be called to start/stop it.  Like @u1686_grawity suggests, I would probably try to simplify everything to avoid forking by splitting this into two simple services (perhaps with a relationship such as BindsTo=).
In your case, you also have a pipe to send data from pythonScriptA to B, but if those are just connected to stdin and stdout, you could do this easily using a systemd socket with ListenFifo= or even a bash command like ExecStart=bash -c "callPythonScriptA | callPythonScriptB"
# /etc/systemd/system/pythonScriptA.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/callPythonScriptA
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/pythonScriptB.service
[Unit]
BindsTo=pythonScriptA.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/callPythonScriptB
Restart=on-failure

Then just sudo systemctl start pythonScriptA.service.  The fifo will be created, and pythonScriptB.service will start as soon as pythonScriptA writes its first data to the fifo.

If your os.pipe() is simply connected to stdin and stdout of callPythonScriptA and callPythonScriptB, you can make that work too using a combination of systemd.socket's ListenFifo= and StandardInput=socket.

However, if you want to stick with forking (maybe this would require modifying 1000 lines of existing code), then it is possible to continue in your direction.  It looks like systemd is not correctly guessing the mainPID of the service.  Therefore, I would make explicit use of PIDFile=.
Here's the man page (man systemd.service) explanation of Type=forking:

If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the main service process, and the service manager will consider the unit started when the parent process exits. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX services. If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can reliably identify the main process of the service.  systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the parent process exits.

And here is the literature on PIDFile=:

Takes a path referring to the PID file of the service. Usage of this option is recommended for services where Type= is set to forking. The path specified typically points to a file below /run/.  If a relative path is specified it is hence prefixed with /run/. The service manager will read the PID of the main process of the service from this file after start-up of the service. The service manager will not write to the file configured here, although it will remove the file after the service has shut down if it still exists. The PID file does not need to be owned by a privileged user, but if it is owned by an unprivileged user additional safety restrictions are enforced: the file may not be a symlink to a file owned by a different user (neither directly nor indirectly), and the PID file must refer to a process already belonging to the service.

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/script-as-daemon
RestartSec=5s
Restart=always
RuntimeMaxSec=infinity
PIDFile=%t/pythonService.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

In your code, it looks like the "second child" might be the main process. It's important to write your PID to that PIDFIle= and you can access that path through the PIDFILE environment variable. as described in man systemd.exec:

$PIDFILE  The path to the configured PID file, in case the process is forked off on behalf of a service that uses the PIDFile= setting, see systemd.service(5) for details. Service code may use this environment variable to automatically generate a PID file at the location configured in the unit file. This field is set to an absolute path in the file system.

Assuming the "second child" is the process you want to track, you could to this:
def createDaemon():
    ...
    if (pid == 0):    # The second child.
       os.chdir(WORKDIR)
       os.umask(UMASK)

       # New lines here
       with open(os.environ['PIDFILE'], 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
           f.write(str(os.getpid()))

    else:
        os._exit(0)    # Exit parent (the first child) of the second child.

    ...

Otherwise decide whether callPythonScriptA or callPythonScriptB is your main process (the one whose exit will be considered by systemd as the end of the service) and update your second snippet:
input, output = os.pipe()
pid           = os.fork()

if pid:
    os.close(input)
    with open(os.environ['PIDFILE'], 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(str(os.getpid()))

    callPythonScriptA
else:
    os.close(output)
    callPythonScriptB


I think you're using an overly broad definition of "forking" here. Avoiding Type=forking does not preclude the script from using fork() in general. It specifically relates to the startup behavior.

Normally, Type=forking should deal with that – unless it guesses the "main" PID of the program incorrectly, which can happen in some cases. In your script, the most likely issue is that "parent of the first child" exits too early – the exit of the initial process is what triggers main-process detection (as well as transition to 'active' state), and if the "parent of the first child" is detected as the main PID but immediately exits after spawning yet another child, then the service
A script doesn't need to daemonize in order to work with systemd; it already runs in a clean environment. So you can switch to a different type if you want:

To use Type=notify, edit the script to:
def sd_notify(*args):
    import os
    import socket

    path = os.environ.get("NOTIFY_SOCKET")
    if not path:
        return
    if path[0] == "@":
        path = "\0" + path[1:]
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    args = "\n".join(*args).encode("utf-8")
    sock.sendto(args, path)

def createDaemon():
    os.chdir(WORKDIR)
    sd_notify("READY=1")


To use Type=simple, edit the script to:
def createDaemon():
    os.chdir(WORKDIR)

The small downside of Type=simple is that the .service unit goes into the 'active' state immediately, so if you have any other services depending on this one, they might start too early.


